# How to return max in ArrayList when two values are tied for max?

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, methods

So far, I have this method, which is supposed to find the max age of a ArrayList. However, in my data, I have two values that are tied at 58 for joint max. How do I get the second 58 from this loop? the index of the first 58 is 1, but the index I need is 4. I cannot hard code.

```
public static int maxAge (ArrayList<Integer> ages) {
        int hold = 0;
        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ages.size(); i++) {
            if (max < ages.get(i)) {
                max = ages.get(i);
                hold = i;
            }
            else i++;       
        }
        return hold;
    }
```

Comment: [ArrayList#lastIndexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#lastIndexOf-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: Do you want to return _both_ results, or just the last one?

Comment: if just the leas one change if equation like 
 if (max < ages.get(i))
to
 if (max <=ages.get(i))

Comment: *Unrelated:* Remove that `else i++;`. It causes incorrect results, since it'll skip elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply change your condition to:

`if (max <= ages.get(i))`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on why you want the other 58. If you want to return the latest match, you can just loop backwards.

Answer (score 0):

The code below, will enable you return all the indexes associated with the maximum value of your list. But you must run it on Java 8 since it use Lambda Expressions.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> maxAge (ArrayList<Integer> ages ) {
        int max = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer> maxIndexes = new ArrayList<Integer>() ;
        for (int i = 0; i < ages.size(); i++) {
            if (max <= ages.get(i)) {
                final int finalMax = max ;
                final int finalIndex = i ;
                maxIndexes.removeIf((elt)-> finalMax < ages.get(finalIndex)) ;
                maxIndexes.add(i) ;
                max = ages.get(i) ;
            }               
        }
        return maxIndexes ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know, is ugly. But I would try to write a functional version.

```
Optional<Integer> max = ages.stream()
                            .max(Integer::compare);
if (max.isPresent()) {
  return IntStream.range(0, ages.size())
                  .mapToObj(pos -> {
                    return new int[] {pos, ages.get(pos)};
                  })
                  .filter(pair -> pair[1] == max.get())
                  .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new))
                  .getLast()[0];
} else
  return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to change the condition to fit your description. Try this:

```
public static int maxAge (ArrayList<Integer> ages) {
    int hold = 0;
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ages.size(); i++) {
        if (max < ages.get(i) || max == ages.get(i) {
            max = ages.get(i);
            hold = i;
        }
        else i++;       
    }
    return hold;
}
```